# Huawei Analytics - Cannot view event parameter

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

We are trying to set up custom parameter in Huawei HMS analytics. Using below snippets and  configured the parameter ID and Parameter name under Event in Connect.

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("exam_difficulty", "high");
bundle.putString("exam_level", "1-1");
bundle.putString("exam_time", "20190520-08");
instance.onEvent("begin_examination", bundle);
```

Issue is we cant see the event parameter. Please can somebody clear this doubt. Please refer attached screenshot.
[image]

[image]

Comment: hi@KirubaPradeep, could you provide a project overview, a real-time overview, and a screenshot after the event analysis time is updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cannot  view the custom parameters of the reported events on the Real-time overview or event analysis page possible cause could may be custom parameters are not added to the Event management page.

Check whether custom parameters of events have been added on the Event management page. To add a custom parameter, go to HUAWEI Analytics > Management > Events. On the Event management page, click Edit, add a custom parameter, and click Add.

For details , please refer to: https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/javascript-custom-events-0000001051597159

FYI:

In the data reports (such as event analysis reports and retention analysis reports) of Analytics Kit, the real-time trend is updated in minutes, and all other indicators are updated the next day. After integrating Analytics Kit into your app, view the data reports on the next day.

Meanwhile you can view report to the Real-time overview page within same day . If there is no data displayed on the Real-time overview page , then possible cause could may be the debug mode is not disabled, and therefore the reported event data is displayed on the App debugging page, not the Real-time overview page.

Solution

Check whether debugMode enabled is displayed in local logs. If so, the debug mode is not disabled. Run the following command and try again:

adb shell setprop debug.huawei.hms.analytics.app .none.

For more details , please refer to our FAQ:

https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/commissioning-faq-0000001050164019